# SQLlite functions on date format YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS+0000

Tags: sql, sqlite, date, date-difference

```
select  
    datetime(SVMXC__Scheduled_Date_Time__c), 
    SVMXC__Scheduled_Date_Time__c 
from table_a
```

Return a null for the datetime function.

I would like to get the difference between

```
datetime(SVMXC__Scheduled_Date_Time__c) - datetime('now')
```

`2020-04-26T17:45:00.000+0000` is the date stored as a `varchar`.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results.

Comment: The time format in your subject line isn't one sqlite understands, and subtracting the string returned by `datetime()` isn't going to work anyways. See https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: 2020-04-26T17:45:00.000+0000 is the date stored as a varchar.Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, you need your date to have a format that SQLite recognizes. Here are two options.

If the offset is always `+0000`, as shown in the question, then you can just remove it. This gives you format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS`, which SQLite understands:

```
substr(SVMXC__Scheduled_Date_Time__c, 1, 23)
```

With this value at hand, you can then use `julianday()` to compute the difference to now, as a number of days:

```
select
    SVMXC__Scheduled_Date_Time__c,
    julianday(substr(SVMXC__Scheduled_Date_Time__c, 1, 23)) - julianday('now') diff
from mytable
```

--

On the other hand, if you do need to take the offset into account, then SQLite expects `:` between hours and minute, so you need to insert it in the string:

```
substr(SVMXC__Scheduled_Date_Time__c, 1, 25) 
    || ':' 
    || substr(SVMXC__Scheduled_Date_Time__c, 1, -2)
```

Then:

```
select
    SVMXC__Scheduled_Date_Time__c,
    julianday(
        substr(SVMXC__Scheduled_Date_Time__c, 1, 25) 
            || ':' 
            || substr(SVMXC__Scheduled_Date_Time__c, 1, -2)
    ) - julianday('now') diff
from mytable
```